# Cabal install (Cabal cabal-install) fails due to missing zlib library

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I want to install Cabal 3.4.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

```sh
$ sudo apt install cabal-install
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.4.0.0

$ sudo cabal update
$ sudo cabal install Cabal cabal-install
...
Starting     zlib-0.6.2.3
Failed to install zlib-0.6.2.3
Build log ( /root/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.6.5/zlib-0.6.2.3-93Wbo8gIIzI9bg4p2MsNUF.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-126381/zlib-0.6.2.3'
Configuring zlib-0.6.2.3...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing (or bad) header file: zlib.h
* Missing (or bad) C library: z
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-3.4.0.0-3glzV3hM64DLoOfz3dHKsn depends on cabal-install-3.4.0.0
which failed to install.
hackage-security-0.6.0.1-KiAyVYLxooJAP3ckeQHnBD depends on
hackage-security-0.6.0.1 which failed to install.
zlib-0.6.2.3-93Wbo8gIIzI9bg4p2MsNUF failed during the configure step. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The error says:

> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
> provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version).

How can I install this package on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, this worked! How did you find this information (so I can find it myself next time)?

Comment: Command `apt-cache` can be useful. Try "apt-cache search zlib". See [related SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/281022/how-do-i-install-zlib-on-debian-6)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aim to install the [**`cabal-install`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install). This package has a dependency that here produces a problem: the [**`zlib`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib).

This `zlib` package is essentially a thin wrapper around the [**`zlib`** C library [wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib). As the error says however, you did not install the `zlib` library, or at least not its package where one can develop with the `zlib` library.

We can install this by installing the [**`libghc-zlib-dev`** software package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libghc-zlib-dev), for example with:

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-zlib-dev
```

If we inspect the [package details on Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libghc-zlib-dev), we see that essentially this is a package that will install the `zlib1g-dev` package, the package to develop software with the `zlib` library. We can thus decide to install `libghc-zlib-dev`, or `zlib1g-dev` with:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` had no effect, but `sudo apt-get install libghc-zlib-dev` did it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nixos Users append `pkgs.haskellPackages.zlib` to `environment.systemPackages`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).